# find the index of an Element in Elements

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm trying to find the index of an Element in Elements, that is its place in the sequence of commentNumber where it occurred previously in the following for loop.

```
    Elements comments = qaDoc.select("li[data-comment-id]");

    commentNumber = 0;

    for (Element comment : comments) {
        commentNumber = commentNumber + 1;

        reply = comment.select("a[class$=d2-in-reply-to]").first();
        replyToId = reply.attr("data-action-target");

        //How do you find the index of the following element??? Thanks
        comments.select("li[data-comment-id=" + replyToId + "]").first();
    }
```

if there is a method like

```
comments.select("li[data-comment-id=" + replyToId + "]").first().indexOf();
```

what do I need to import to get access to it. I've only been programming java and jsoup for a week now and have a lot to learn yet. Thanks

Comment: What is the use of 'commentNumber'? It appears to me that THAT is the index you are looking for (-1)?

Comment: no the current commentNumber is not what I'm after but the commentNumber or a previous comment being replied to that occurred earlier in the loop. Anyway replyToNumber = 1 + comments.indexOf(comments.select("li[data-comment-id=" + replyToId + "]").first());

gets me what I needed

Answer (score 0):

Using the assignment below, I was able to solve the problem.

```
replyToNumber = 1 + comments.indexOf(comments.select("li[data-comment-id=" + replyToId + "]").first());
```